# Close SPDialog after using Response.TransmitFile

Tags: javascript, response, codebehind, spdialog, close

I am using some javascript to open a dialog like this:

```
var options = {
    title: "Generate Report",
    url: "/_layouts/ConfirmPrint.aspx",
    dialogReturnValueCallback : Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback),
    width: 500
 };

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

I usually close my dialog from code behind using Response.Write(....window.frame...), as shown below. This script doesn't get written when using .TransmitFile.

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=APReport.pdf");
    Response.TransmitFile(path);
    Response.End();

    //This doesn't work yet
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
}
```

I tried firing the code in a different order as well as removing Response.End. What would an alternative be to closing the dialog after transmission of my file??

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me.

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", "SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(0, 0);", true);
```

Comment: This will close the dialog if used alone. But does nothing when called before or after Response.TransmitFile

Comment: try adding button client click, as response.end may be causing issue. follow this article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256209/jquery-dialog-doesnt-close-from-code-behind-after-a-response-transmitfile

Comment: something like this: <asp:Button ID="yourbtnId" runat="server" Text="Buttontext" OnClientClick="window.frameElement.commitPopup();" onclick="btnCancel_Click" />

Comment: Thanks for the link. Still doesn't work though. The Server event isn't being hit.

Comment: Looks like I need to return true after .commitPopup() in order for the server event to hit. But return true; after your code doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, it works for me:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "msg", "window.frameElement.cancelPopUp();", true);
```

Comment: This also close the dialog. But only when used alone and doesn't work if called before or after .TransmitFile